# flutter authentication failure 401

Tags: http, authentication, flutter, get

guys i really need help on that
i want to access this website (http://1.0.0.1/orion/summary.aspx) it redirect me to this website (http://1.0.0.1/orion/login.aspx) i tried many authentications tech but it didn't work all give 401 sample of the code is below

```
'''
Future getData() async {
//  NTLMClient ntlmClient = new NTLMClient(
//    domain: "xxa.com",
//    workstation: "10.0.0.1",
//    username: "user",
//    password: "password",
//  );
String username = 'user';
String password = 'password';
String basicAuth = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
print(basicAuth);
var client = http.Client();
final loginResponse = await client.post('http://10.0.0.1/Orion/Login.aspx', body: (basicAuth),
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': '$username:$password'});
http.Response response = await client.get('http://10.0.0.1/Orion/SummaryView.aspx',
    headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
);
print(loginResponse.statusCode);
print(loginResponse.headers);
print(loginResponse.body);
print(response.statusCode);
print(response.body);
```

'''

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: you should edit your title and remove the "really need support" stuff. Instead write something like "401 in Flutter REST call" or something. Furthermore its impossible to give a response without seing backend code.

Comment: tell me what back-end code you want to see ?

Comment: only respond i got is from someone asking me change your title !!!!!